# Node modules local changes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, node-modules

I have a problem with web storm and github, I guess.

After I made some local changes in Local Changes appears some random files from node modules [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zWPR8.jpg). I didn't touch those files but it looks like I changed something.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you haven't added `node_modules` to your `.gitignore` file.

Add `node_modules/` as a new line in that `.gitignore` file or create a new one. That way git will ignore any changes made in these files.

Comment: I added node_modules to .gitignore, still reproducing